# Database design for aggregate data (containing duplicate records)

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I'm looking to generate statistics based on the MySQL database - but I'm having issue in designing the proper database schema for it.

**Scenario :**

- User has a bunch of machines which upload their software list to the server
- These machines, individually, may upload 1-3 times per day, or upload once every few days (basically not consistent)
- Server will store these machines + software list data in MySQL database

**Application:**

- User is able to specify a time frame (in days) to view statistics for these machines

**Type of statistics :**

1. Graph (daily unique software count) - in that specified time frame, it will show the total count of unique software that was uploaded across all machines on each day
2. Top 3 software - in that specified time frame, it will show what were the top 3 software (sorted desc by how many unique machines had this software before)
3. Top 3 machines with most software - in that specified time frame, it will show the top 3 machines that were once detected with the most software

**Example Scenario :**

- Machine 1 uploaded "Software A", "Software B" and "Software C" on Feb 14 2021
- Machine 2 uploaded "Software C", "Software D" and "Software E" on Feb 15 2021
- Machine 2 uploaded (again) "Software C", "Software D", "Software E" and "Software F" on Feb 15 2021
- Machine 3 uploaded "Software A", "Software D" and "Software F" on Feb 16 2021
- Machine 4 uploaded "Software A", "Software C", "Software D" on Feb 17 2021
- Machine 5 uploaded "Software X" on Feb 17 2021

And the data is stored in the following table:

| DateTime | MachineNo | Software |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14/02/2021 09:00:00 | 1 | A |
| 14/02/2021 09:00:00 | 1 | B |
| 14/02/2021 09:00:00 | 1 | C |
| 15/02/2021 09:00:00 | 2 | C |
| 15/02/2021 09:00:00 | 2 | D |
| 15/02/2021 09:00:00 | 2 | E |
| 15/02/2021 20:00:00 | 2 | C |
| 15/02/2021 20:00:00 | 2 | D |
| 15/02/2021 20:00:00 | 2 | E |
| 15/02/2021 20:00:00 | 2 | F |
| 16/02/2021 13:00:00 | 3 | A |
| 16/02/2021 13:00:00 | 3 | D |
| 16/02/2021 13:00:00 | 3 | F |
| 17/02/2021 15:00:00 | 4 | A |
| 17/02/2021 15:00:00 | 4 | C |
| 17/02/2021 15:00:00 | 4 | D |
| 17/02/2021 21:00:00 | 5 | X |

(Table A)

- **NOTE** : For MachineNo 2, the reason why I insert original entries again  on **15/02/2021 20:00:00** (instead of just adding "Software F") is because I wish to have a full history of the machine upload.

As such, if I were to view the time frame for **14/02/2021 to 17/02/2021**, the statistics will be as follow :

- Graph (daily unique software count)

| Date (x-axis) | Unique Software Count (y-axis) |
| --- | --- |
| 14/02/2021 | 3 |
| 15/02/2021 | 4 |
| 16/02/2021 | 3 |
| 17/02/2021 | 4 |

- Top 3 software (sorted desc by how many unique machines had this software before)

| Software | How many unique machines had this software before |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 3 |

- Top 3 machines with most software

| MachineNo | Highest number of software |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |

Issue :

- Now instead of the machine uploading just few software data, there are potentially hundred to thousands software per upload. Also, there will be hundred to thousands of machines.
  As such, I'm worried about the storage space being used up very quick.

Question :

- Is there any other ways where I can design the database schema such that I won't be storing so much data (like table A), and still able to generate the 3 required statistics on-the-fly?